# Why is burial preferred over cremation for enlightened beings and children?

Tags: death, cremation

For enlightened beings and children, the order of preference is burial over cremation, there are exceptions though like Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Swami Vivekananda were cremated.

Some people say enlightened being and children are not attached to the body so they are buried and other beings are attached to body so they are cremated.

Even if this reason is true then also why not cremate enlightened beings and children instead of burying? Is burial better than cremation? Or any other reason is mentioned in any scripture in favor of burial over cremation?

Comment: Where did you come across the notion that burial is the preferred mode for enlightened human beings and children?

Comment: you are conflating two different questions into one. Break your question into 2, one for children, another for sadhus.

Comment: @Carmensandiego For Sannyasis and children cremation is not prescribed. See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24074/4732

Comment: @Rickross - But sannyasis are not same as enlightened human beings. Noted about children

Comment: Yes we can only talk about Sannyasis and children. Not all Sannyasis are enlightened. @Carmensandiego

Comment: on account of sadhana the residual positive energy is still there in the bodies of living being.. in order for ordinary or normal people to get uplifted from this residual positive energy on account of sadhana done by seers they are buried.. its burnt up oil lamp still have oil as residue until it evaporates but for kids the amount karma is not started no piece of energy is there its left to soil.. it will dissolve in few years whereas samsarin many with negative energy only..take the life like ramakrsihna pramhamsa can be buried but due to practice norms it was done..

Comment: @Rickross - agree. And not all enlightened beings are sannyasis